# Plot single state ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

How do I plot a single state with borders on ggmap? I tried using get_map with location='massachusetts' but the whole state is only in view when the region is zoomed out. Can I isolate a state and plot it separately with ggmap?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have mention/provide what is your input data.

Comment: with great difficulty. can you isolate a state in google maps or openstreetmap (etc)? ggmap is just using the tile APIs from those services. You'd have to have the MA state border, invert it to the clipping region area and overlay a polygon on top with whatever background color you're using. using `ggplot::geom_map()` or `leaflet` with a MA shapefile. You won't have the tiles but they aren't necessary and are usually used improperly anyway.

Comment: I'm using ggmaps for the first time for a final project for my intro to R class. Do you have any example code I can follow along with? Thanks!

Comment: Check [out this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155334/ggmap-clip-a-map)